# Google transit json parsing directions

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I'm able to retrive the data from google transit api using the langitude and latitude but not with `directions` attribute.. This is what i done so far

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
            try
            {
                String Lat=Double.toString(22.508507985602836);
                String Long=Double.toString(73.474991977022533);

                String Address = ReadAddressFromWebService(Lat,Long);
                Toast.makeText(this,Address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("error","Json parsing error :"+ e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }

    public String ReadAddressFromWebService(String latitude, String longitude) {
            String Address="";
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+
              latitude +","+longitude +"&sensor=false");
                String url=sb.toString();
            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

            Log.i("","HTTP client created");
            String responseData="";
        try {
            HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            response.addHeader("Accept-Language", "it-IT");
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            Log.i("", "HTTP Response arrived");

            BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader((entity.getContent()),"UTF-8"));
            String line="";
            Log.i("","Start buffre reading");

        while((line=bf.readLine())!=null){
            responseData=responseData+line;
        }

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseData);

            JSONArray resultArry = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

            Address = resultArry.getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address").toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Address;
    }
}
```

i tried to change the `StringBuffer` in this way: `sb.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+
              latitude +"&destination="+longitude +"&sensor=false");`

but the toast i use to see the result doesn't show anything.. is empty and i get an JSONObject error in line: Address = `resultArry.getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address").toString();`

so, this is the json i would parse: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=vicenza&destination=costabissara&sensor=false

and i would display the route.. of course i changed:

`JSONArray resultArry = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

```
        Address = resultArry.getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address").toString();`
```

to

`JSONArray resultArry = jsonObj.getJSONArray("routes");

```
        Address = resultArry.getJSONObject(0).getString("legs").toString();`
```

but without success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your example and it worked. The only change I had to do was instead of passing coordinates to `ReadAddressFromWebService` I passed the origin and destination strings:

```
String from = "vicenza";
String to = "costabissara";

String Address = ReadAddressFromWebService(from,to);
```

`origin` and `destination` works with location names not coordinates.

Comment: thank you, you're right..but, in this way i can set 2 different cities.. how could i retrive the destination using 2 addresses of same city? I don't know if you understand..

Comment: @End.Game [Here's an exampe](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=ViaEugenioMontale36077,Vicenza,Italy&destination=StradadelleCaperse,15536100Casale,Vicenza,Italy&sensor=false). You just simply Separate the address,city and country by a comma. You can get the full addresses from [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com).